# solution for echo to replace globally

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, grep

How do I replace `echo` in all my ksh scripts to `echo -e`.
Example:

### Input

Script containing following lines,

```
echo "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
set echo off
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
```

### OUTPUT:

I should not disturb set echo off command and only change the printing echo commands. If already it is changed to `echo -e`, I should not replace again. I should replace it in a single shot for all the scripts from root directory.

```
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
set echo off
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
sed 's/^echo "/echo -e "/' filename
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat tmp
echo "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
set echo off
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/^echo "/echo -e "/' tmp
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
set echo off
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
```

`find` and `exec`:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type f -name "*.ksh" -exec sed -i"bak" 's/^echo "/echo -e "/' {} \;
```

Comment: find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/^echo "/echo -e "/g' . This will work right.

Comment: woah! I would put a `-name` or `-regex` in my `find` and check the output first. You are performing `sed` replacement `in-line` so you should be a little careful. Always better to do `sed -i"bak" …` so that you make a backup copy of your files. Also, I am not too fond of `xargs`. I would prefer `-exec`, and you will need buffer at the end where you will be passing filename to `sed` something like this `{}` `\;`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/echo [^-]/s/echo/echo -e/'
```

Look for `echo` followed by a space and something other than a dash; replace the `echo` with `echo -e`.  Apply it in a loop to the files you want to change.

```
for file in *.sh
do
    sed '/echo [^-]/s/echo/echo -e/' $file > tmp.$$
    mv tmp.$$ $file
done
```

Comment: I liked your solution better than mine. So much for self-confidence. Sigh! :(

Comment: I like this too! what about `echo off` though?

Comment: Yours works fine.  There are minor issues with both.  Yours won't find an indented `echo`, or the one in `if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then echo "File $file not found 1>&2; fi`.  Mine will find the echo in `boxecho "This stuff"` and replace it with `boxecho -e "This stuff"`.  Neither is entirely satisfactory, but the workarounds depend on the version of `sed` available.  Also, yours will replace `echo -e "Something"` with `echo -e -e "Something"` which mine won't.  They can be combined by using the anchor (`^`) for one substitution, and a space (or tab) before `echo` to deal with other cases.

Comment: There are still odd-ball corner cases for sloppy (or do I mean parsimonious) coders who put `echo` immediately after a semi-colon, for example, with no space: `if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then ls -l "$file";echo "The contents:";cat "$file"; fi`, and other such tricks.  It is hard to deal with all possible vagaries, but few people actually exploit all of them, and a much simpler script does for a particular job than is needed as a generic conversion tool.  Both our scripts get confused if the `echo` is not the command: `: echo is not appropriate here`.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust regex would be look for `echo`  not followed by  `-e` or `off` in any context:
Since `sed` can't do lookarounds in regex you'd have to use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/echo +(?!((-[A-Za-df-z]|--[a-z-]+) +)*(-e|off))/echo -e/'
```

This also handles the case that you might have (e.g.) `echo -n -e` where there *is* a `-e`, but not directly after the `echo`: you don't want to end up with `echo -e -n -e`. Also, if you did (say) `echo --version`, you wouldn't want a `echo -e --version`. The above regex takes care of these.

INPUT

```
echo "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
set echo off
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
echo -n -e "what happens if the -e is already there?"
echo --help # don't want echo -e --help
```

OUTPUT

```
echo -e"\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
set echo off
echo -e "\nE-MAILING TO INTERESTED PARTIES....\n"
echo -n -e "what happens if the -e is already there?"
echo -e--help # don't want echo -e --help
```

Comment: Thanks for providing different view on it.

Comment: Doesn't `echo off` simply echo '`off`'?

Comment: Sure, but not with `set` in front of it.